# Where are Rare Treasurefish?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I need to defeat at least five Rare Treasurefish (probably more, in Treasure Hunt panels I can't read the requirements for yet).

Where can I find Rare Treasurefish? Are they visually different from regular treasurefish? I feel like I've shot a ton of fish, but apparently only one was rare so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slight Spoilers:

Rare Treasurefish have a golden hue where the hold the chests at. I have seen one in chapter 8, when you are outside of the space pirate ship. There is also another one in chapter 11, while you are in the maze. Just play those levels a few times, and you should get it.

Comment: I've confirmed the presence of one in chapter 8, in the first section on the ship's hull. Once you know what you're looking for it's hard to miss.